# Which single-byte charset matches first 0x100 unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Is there a single-byte charset (e.g. ISO-8859-x) that matches the first 256 unicode characters (i.e. characters [\u0000-\u00FF](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF)) exactly or almost exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 matches the first Unicode code points the closest, by design.

Comment: Not to be confused with "ISO 8859-1" (note the missing hyphen after "ISO"), which does not define any values in its 0x00-0x1F and 0x7F-0x9F codeunits.  "ISO-8859-1" updates "ISO 8859-1" to fill in the missing values, and became the basis for Unicode's Latin-1 codepoints (U-0000 to U-00FF).  "Windows-1252" matches "ISO 8859-1" but defines values for its 0x80-0x9F codeunits that are different than what "ISO-8859-1" defines.

Comment: How does one "not confuse" that?  :)